# PHP unexpected end

Tags: php

Assuming that a valid login is being POSTed, I am having some issues with my code ending immediately before the setcookie function. Here's my code.

```
<?php

echo 'v1.3.4';

require_once '../ssi/mysql.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
$checknm = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checknm == 1){
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){
        $keypair = $info['keypair'];
        setcookie("f2admin", $keypair, time()+3600);
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}else{
    $err = "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again.";
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so a couple things I noticed.

1. The `header()` is set above `echo 'YES';` which means that the page will redirect prior to outputting content (echoing).
2. The `exit;` is set above `echo 'NO';` which means that the page will exit prior to reaching `echo 'No';`.
3. There is an echo set above the `header()` causing the header() redirect to not work.

On a side note, if you are trying to stop the while loop, the function should be `break;` instead of `exit;`

---

Update

I've got it working properly in my local environment. I found a couple things.

1) there is no action set in the form (not sure if needed).

2) The $err is never echoed (hence the blank page), however the code itself does actually work.

3) The mysqli_fetch_array loop is redundant since you are forcing mysql to LIMIT results to 1.

```
$info = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
$keypair = $info['keypair'];
setcookie("f2admin", $keypair, time()+3600);
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: I added the echos of Yes and No to see if my server was skipping lines and to find out where it was stopping.

Comment: So, just a heads up, but your revised (updated) code lacks the `header()` redirect, hence why its not being forwarded.

How do you know the cookie isn't being set?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed the header while copying it from Dreamweaver. I have a cookie editor in my browser.

Comment: No worries.

On the index page, what do you get when you put var_dump($_COOKIE)?

Comment: array(1) { ["__atuvc"]=> string(4) "1|49" }

Comment: Try to remove the echo regarding the version at the top (or at least comment it out) as it may be interfering with both the `setcookie()` and `header()`. Also, have you got error_reporting enabled? (if not, or unsure, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. If so, do you have any output?

Comment: Alright, so I moved the version at the very end of the PHP. I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and got nothing. If you give me a moment, I will get you a link to show you what I'm actually seeing.

Comment: The URL: http://stackoverflow.awscorp.net/login.php
Test User: test
Test Password: foo

Provided you type a correct login, the intention is for you to be directed to index.php otherwise show an "Incorrect Login" message (which works)

Comment: I am getting just a blank page after trying to login, indicating that the header() isn't working properly. Can you ensure that the code in the OP is up-to-date?

Comment: Right, I'm getting the same error. I did take a look at my cookies, and `setcookie` isn't doing anything either.

Running PHP ver5.3

Comment: Can you please add a safe version of the ssi/mysql.php file so I can try to replicate it here locally?

Comment: `<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.server.com","username","password","db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?> `

By the way, thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: Alright, sorry about the delay commenting back. I've got it working properly in my local environment. I found a couple things. 1) there is no action set in the form (not sure if needed). 2) The `$err` is never echoed (hence the blank page), however the code itself does actually work. 3) The mysqli_fetch_array loop is redundant since you are forcing mysql to LIMIT results to 1. There must be something else going on. I've updated the answer above with a copy of my local code. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Your code helped. Thank you so much. On my side, I had an HTML form with a hidden field named action, and the err did work if you typed a wrong password.

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove/comment `echo` anything before using `header`

```
if($checknm == 1){
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){
        $keypair = $info['keypair'];
        //echo 'Keypair: '.$keypair;
        setcookie("f2admin", $keypair, time()+3600);
        header('Location: index.php');
        echo 'YES ';
        exit;
        echo 'NO ';
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed all the echos and the cookie is still not being set, nor is the page forwarding to index.php

Comment: where you have placed this code? you should use this code before any output to browser.

Comment: Give me just a moment and I will add the entire PHP code to the question.

Comment: so are you getting result in $info inside while loop?

Comment: Yes, I can echo the $keypair variable and get an accurate result.

Comment: still you have `echo 'v1.3.4';` on first line.

Comment: So if I move the `echo v1.3.4` to after the header, should it work?

Comment: why you have written this? yes write it down at end then header will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot output anything before doing anything with `header`. Output must be after the header information.